# Group By Month and Year to get distinct month and years then combine as a single date SQL

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE,CAST([Year] AS VARCHAR(4))+'-'+
                    CAST([Month] AS VARCHAR(2))+'-'+
                    CAST('1' AS VARCHAR(2))) Date 
FROM (SELECT YEAR(Date) as [Year], MONTH(Date) as [Month] FROM [dbo].[Data] 
GROUP BY YEAR(Date), MONTH(Date)) x
                    ORDER BY Date DESC
```

Is there a better way to doinq this with a single query?

The query should return the unique month and year from a table but as combined Date.

Comment: You should post some sample data of your table and the desired result

Comment: Please tag your version of sql-server

Answer (score 1):

```
IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..#TempT') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TempT
CREATE TABLE #TempT(
    dt datetime)

INSERT INTO #TempT (dt) VALUES
('2016-10-11'),
('2016-10-3'),
('2016-9-13'),
('2016-9-16')

SELECT DISTINCT CAST(DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, dt), 0) as DATE) AS Dates
from #TempT
```

Answer (score 1):

Sample data is really a necessity for these kinds of questions, but this function could also be a help for you [DATEFROMPARTS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213228.aspx#Anchor_0)

```
SELECT 
  DATEFROMPARTS([Year], [Month], 01)
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    YEAR(Date) as [Year], 
    MONTH(Date) as [Month] 
  FROM [dbo].[Data] 
  GROUP BY YEAR(Date), MONTH(Date)
) x
ORDER BY Date DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

This code takes whatever date you enter and evaluates it as the first of the month.  Effectively looking at only month and year:

```
SELECT
    DATEADD(MM,DATEDIFF(MM,0, [Date] ),0) AS [YearMonth]
FROM [dbo].[Data]
ORDER BY
    DATEADD(MM,DATEDIFF(MM,0, [Date] ),0)
;
```